# Cómo validar campos de tabla que devuelven NULL?

Tags: javascript, html5, json

Hola buenas tardes tengo una duda y no se como validarla, tengo esta tabla donde se llenan todos los campos con un json.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me muestra todos los datos pero quiero hacer una validacion para que los datos que estan en null los ponga en blanco.

Con esta parte de código valido que el json no venga vació para que no truene,  solo que nada mas valida el json

```
f (datos.lAdjoiningModel != null) {
                for (var i = 0; i < datos.lAdjoiningModel.length; i++) {
                    let tbMC = document.querySelector('#tbMC');
                    if (i%2==0) {
                        tbMC.innerHTML += `
                        <tr>
                            <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; height: 25px; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">${datos.lAdjoiningModel[i].typeTerrains}</td>
                            <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; height: 25px; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">${datos.lAdjoiningModel[i].typeDirection}</td>
                            <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; height: 25px; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">${datos.lAdjoiningModel[i].measure}</td>
                            <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; height: 25px; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">${datos.lAdjoiningModel[i].description}</td>
                        </tr>`;
                    }else{
                        tbMC.innerHTML += `
                        <tr class="even">
                            <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; height: 25px; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">${datos.lAdjoiningModel[i].typeTerrains}</td>
                            <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; height: 25px; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">${datos.lAdjoiningModel[i].typeDirection}</td>
                            <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; height: 25px; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">${datos.lAdjoiningModel[i].measure}</td>
                            <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; height: 25px; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">${datos.lAdjoiningModel[i].description}</td>
                        </tr>`;
                    }    
                }
            }else{
                let tbMC = document.querySelector('#tbMC');
                tbMC.innerHTML += `
                <tr>
                    <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; height: 25px; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;"></td>
                    <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; height: 25px; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;"></td>
                    <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; height: 25px; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;"></td>
                    <td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; height: 25px; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;"></td>
                </tr>`;
            }
```

para validarlo probé haciendo lo siguiente pero no funciona claro dentro del mismo for para que no marque error

```
if(datos.lAdjoiningModel[i].typeDirection != null){
campo
}else{
campo vacio
}
```

O en el mismo campo poner algo así, pero me marcaba error en el mismo editor de texto

```
<td style=" font-size: 11px;border: 1px solid black !important; height: 25px; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; font-size: 11px; text-align: center;">${(datos.lAdjoiningModel[i].typeDirection != null) => datos.lAdjoiningModel[i].typeDirection : " " }</td>
```

Espero que me puedan ayudar de antemano muchas gracias y tambien si hay alguien que me pueda apoyar diciéndome y mostrándome si un dato se puede poner con 2 decimales aunque no tenga.

Comment: Dentro del `for` bastaría con `if(datos.lAdjoiningModel[i].typeDirection === null) { datos.lAdjoiningModel[i].typeDirection = ""; }`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: intenta de esta forma `if(!datos.lAdjoiningModel[i].typeDirection)`

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo utilizar una clase CSS, para los estilos del td, dado que siempre son los mismos

Ahora bien, puedes reducir código usando if ternario, que también te ayuda para saber si el atributo es `null`, si lo es pone `''` de lo contrario pone el valor

```js
if (datos.lAdjoiningModel != null) {
  for (var i = 0; i < datos.lAdjoiningModel.length; i++) {
    let tbMC = document.querySelector('#tbMC');
    tbMC.innerHTML += `<tr class="${(i % 2 == 0)?'':'even'}"><td>${datos.lAdjoiningModel[i].typeTerrains}</td><td>${datos.lAdjoiningModel[i].typeDirection=='null'?'':datos.lAdjoiningModel[i]}</td>
<td>${datos.lAdjoiningModel[i].measure}</td>
<td>${datos.lAdjoiningModel[i].description}</td>
</tr>`;
  }
} else {
  let tbMC = document.querySelector('#tbMC');
  tbMC.innerHTML += `<tr><td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>`;
}
```

```css
td {
  font-size: 11px;
  border: 1px solid black !important;
  height: 25px;
  margin: 0px !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias tratare de hacerlo así porque si son muchas lineas de código